# How to get Oracle VARRAY data type details

Tags: oracle, nested-table, varray

I am migrating tables with nested tables/array to another database so i am trying to create a target structure table with the data element of the nested table and array. I am able to roughly get the column and data type details for nested table from ALL_NESTED_TABLES and ALL_NESTED_TABLE_COLS. However, there could be VARRAYS in the structure as well. HOw do i get the details of a VARRAY. Table ALL_VARRAYS identify the varray but doesnt give the data element its using such as RAW or VARCHAR.

I pick a standard example in a oracle database which is MGMT_JOB_VALUE_PARAMS. I am assuming this is a standard table. Which has three columns.

```
SOURCE_ID
PARAM_VALUES        MGMT_JOB_PARAM_LIST    (nested table)
ACTION
```

MGMT_JOB_PARAM_LIST is broken down further to

```
NESTED_TABLE_ID       RAW
MGMT_JOB_PARAM_RECORD     Varray
MGMT_JOB_VECTOR_PARAMS    Varray
```

Both MGMT_JOB_PARAM_RECORD and MGMT_JOB_VECTOR_PARAMS is available in table ALL_VARRAYS.

I dont have direct access to the Oracle database and only able to call native SQL to select the data.
I am already able to select data for nested table since I am able to create the structure and field names properly.

Hope somebody can help.

Thanks.
Anand Muthu

Looked through various table to find the data structure for varray.
ALL_TYPES looked promising but unable to find the type above in this table.

Comment: post a create table and also data and end result a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `all_varrays` view specifies the type is uses in `type_owner.type_name`. Use that to look up the *collection* type info in `all_coll_types` (not `all_types` which is more generic and not specific to collections). What you are looking for will be in the `elem_type_name` column.